# rtMavenDeployer how do you add properties?

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I found no examples of this

This is how it works with the scripted pipeline:

```
rtMaven.deployer.addProperty("status", "in-qa")
```

rtMavenDeployer however has "properties" and its just a list?: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#rtmavendeployer-set-maven-deployer

```
rtMavenDeployer (
        id: 'deployer-unique-id',
        properties: ????,
        serverId: 'my-server',
        releaseRepo: 'myrepo',
        snapshotRepo: 'myrepo'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a list of properties in the form of ["key1=value1", "key2=value2"].

```
rtMavenDeployer (
        id: 'deployer-unique-id',
        properties: ["key1=value1", "key2=value2"],
        serverId: 'my-server',
        releaseRepo: 'myrepo',
        snapshotRepo: 'myrepo'
)
```

Comment: this is wrong i think getting this: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.declarative.steps.maven.MavenDeployerStep.setProperties() expects java.util.List<java.lang.String> but received class java.lang.String`

Comment: `properties: ["key1=value1","key2=value2"],`

Comment: Right. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @yahavi could you please be so kind to help me with the issue on the similar matter related to plugin to upload maven to artifactory?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091613/jenkins-convert-current-declarative-pipeline-to-maven-upload-pipeline