# Jenkins - convert current declarative pipeline to Maven upload pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins

In Jenkins declarative pipeline I have a job that currently successfully uploads ZIP package to Artifactory Generic repo.

First I run `npm install` and `npm build` scripts, and new generated folder I ZIP it and send to artifactory.

```
sh "npm install"
............
sh "npm run build:qa"
................
            stage ('Artifactory stage') {
                steps {
                    rtServer (
                        id: 'Artifactory',
                        url: 'https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory',
                        credentialsId: 'id'
                    )
                }
            }

        stage ('Build info stage ') {
            steps {
                rtBuildInfo (
                    maxBuilds: 50,
                    deleteBuildArtifacts: true
                )
            }
        }

        stage ('Upload stage') {
            steps {
                rtUpload (
                    serverId: 'Artifactory',
                    spec: '''{
                          "files": [
                            {
                              "pattern": "arena*.zip",
                              "target": "my-generic-snapshot-local/packages/"
                            }
                         ]
                    }''',
                )
            }
```

Now, the same ZIPPED file I would like to send to Maven repo - `test-maven-snapshot-local`.

I saw  on this link https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax
that I should define `rtMavenResolver` `rtMavenDeployer` and `rtMavenRun`.

I would like to keep `npm install and build` logic.

But how do I specify in `rtMaven*` which zip package I want to UPLOAD
to artifactory? I can't find that part.

Also how to define a name of the package how it should be uploaded? also if I want to specify a subfolder of the repo where I want to upload how I could do that? will the `pom` file be automatically generated?

Can someone help me how I should define those 3 methods?

**UPDATE*: I have modified my Jenkinsfile:

```
                rtServer (
                    id: 'Artifactory',
                    url: 'https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory',
                    credentialsId: '9134676',
                    timeout: 300
                )

                rtMavenDeployer (
                id: "MAVEN_DEPLOYER",
                serverId: "Artifactory",
                releaseRepo: "my-generic-release-local",
                snapshotRepo: "my-generic-snapshot-local"
                )

                rtMavenResolver (
                    id: "MAVEN_RESOLVER",
                    serverId: "Artifactory",
                    releaseRepo: "apache-maven-remote",
                    snapshotRepo: "apache-maven-remote"
                )
```

........................

```
stage ('Exec Maven') {
    steps {
        rtMavenRun (
            tool: "maven-3.2.5", // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
            pom: 'pom.xml',
            goals: 'clean install',
            deployerId: "MAVEN_DEPLOYER",
            resolverId: "MAVEN_RESOLVER"
        )
    }
}
```

I specified in my `pom.xml` file name of the folder with artifacts.
`<artifactId>arena-web-ruf</artifactId>`

As a result - I get

```
arena-web-ruf-2022.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
arena-web-ruf-2022.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but .JAR file doesn't contain any useful info except: `META-INF` file with pom.xml and pom.properties file. No code at all.

I would prefer as a result of the Jenkins build to have a ZIPPED package with code on Artifactory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about rtMavenResolver rtMavenDeployer and rtMavenRun, you can simply add another block to your existing rtUpload step, with the maven repo as the target (assuming it's on the same Artifactory instance).

```
spec: '''{
      "files": [
        {
          "pattern": "arena*.zip",
          "target": "my-generic-snapshot-local/packages/"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "arena*.zip",
          "target": "my-maven-snapshot-local/packages/"
        }
     ]
}''',
```

Comment: Hi Denham, thanks first of all for your involvement. I can't use it like this because I need generated POM.XML file as well, which this kind of upload does not provide but only when triggering the full `rtMavenRun build`.
I have updated my question with modified Jenkins file - could you please take a look at the error I am getting?

Comment: I am having difficulties to understand for what purpose is `rtMavenResolves` being used. It seems that Jenkins is trying to download some .jars from the virtual repo that I specified in Resolver (because that is how I usually saw in examples). But I do not have anything there yet. `ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 in artifactory-release (https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory/faselect-generic-release-virtual`

Comment: Can you please assist me where does it search  for these plugins - and actually how I would need to define a Resolver so that it succeeds to download required plugins? Thanks

Comment: If you're using rtMavenRun, you're typically building source code, dependencies defing in the pom.xml.  The rtMavenResolver says which repo to pull required dependencies from. Typically you'd be resolving from somewhere like Maven Central.  Deployer is where the build artifacts will be pushed to.

Comment: I should also point out, The minimum Maven version supported is 3.3.9 (according to the docs, here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax )

Comment: Denham - thanks I correct the Resolvers repos to target some remote `apache repo` and now it's OK.
I got POM file and JAR file but empty (only with META-INF folder) without my files. Can you tell me in simple words - how does build know what folder it should package? I have "arena" folder and my "artifactId" in `pom.xml` is named `arena` but the JAR does not contain my code. How does build knows what it should package? Thank you!!!

Comment: I accepted the answer but could you please take a look at new questions which I raised? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110914/jenkins-and-maven-empty-package-how-to-define-what-should-be-packaged

Comment: It sounds like you might need to read up on Maven a bit more.  The pom will manage dependencies that your code uses. The artifact name, is what you are calling your project (it's not so much the folder). You typically have your src code in `/src`, and when maven runs, it will compile and package.  Often, this means you will end up with a .jar file in `/target` folder. And by default, the Artifactory plugin you are using will try grab those files.

Comment: Denham could you please let me know how and where I should define for my job not to look into `/src` folder but into my custom folder that needs to be zipped? we are not using any of the /src file. what is the property to set  that one? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246750/discussion-between-denham-coote-and-andreys).